# What is the range of HOUR_OF_DAY?

Tags: java, android, calendar

A simple question, but I couldn't find an answer to it:

> Is the range of `HOUR_OF_DAY` between 0 and 23, or 1 and 24?

If I want a random `HOUR_OF_DAY`, do I need:

```
int randomHour = (int) (Math.random() * 24);
```

or

```
int randomHour = (int) (Math.random() * 24 + 1);
```

Comment: It's 0 to 23, as you could have discovered with simple experimentation. I wouldn't use `Math.random() * 24` though - I'd use `Random.nextInt(24)`.

Comment: I found this out the hard way. Java's simpledateformat uses the 1-24 range (so that quarter past midnight is 24:15). Spent a long time debugging.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY):

> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. `HOUR_OF_DAY` is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the `HOUR_OF_DAY` is 22.

If 10:04:15.250 PM is `HOUR_OF_DAY` 22, That would make the range `0` - `23`. If it were `1` to `24`, 10 p.m. would be 23. And that would be wrong on so many levels. :-)

Answer (score 11):

It is 0-23.

I have tested it by running below code

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
    System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Output is 0.

If you run

```
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
```

Output will be 23.

If you run

```
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 25);
```

Output will be 1.

Answer (score 4):

The Range is between 0 to 23

Run this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

If the time is 12 AM the output will be 0

and if the time is 11 PM the output will be 23