# cal.HOUR_OF_DAY, based on 12 or 24?

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to figure out what time of the day it is. If I use:

```
cal.HOUR_OF_DAY
```

and it is currently 11PM, will the method return as 11 or 23?

Or, would I have to use something along these lines:

> ```
>     if (cal.HOUR_OF_DAY == 11 && (cal.AM_PM == cal.PM)) {
>         // do something
>     }
> ```

Comment: Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22

Comment: don't you read the javadoc if you want to use some field/method that you are not sure?

Comment: Exactly. These kinds of questions are solvable without stackoverflow. Someone who doesn't bother reading the javadocs won't ever become even a half-decent programmer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the range of HOUR\_OF\_DAY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168805/what-is-the-range-of-hour-of-day)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY

HOUR_OF_DAY is 24 hour format